# How to make cradled FAB in Jetpack Compose Material 3?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to make a Cradled FAB using Jetpack Compose Material 3. Based on the images  from the documentation on this site: https://m3.material.io/components/bottom-app-bar/implementation
[image: Cradle Fab]

However in the code I can not find anything about where to specify the anchor position or set the fab to docked. The example code is XML and I'm using Compose. How is this done? I'm using Scafold and BottomAppBar now but they don't seem to have any options to dock or cradle or anchor the Floating Action Button.

Comment: Currently (1.0.0-beta03) is not supported

Comment: According to that same link in the description ( https://m3.material.io/components/bottom-app-bar/overview ) "M3: Bottom app bar has new colors, a taller container, no elevation or shadow, and **contains** the FAB."

Answer (score 3):

Google recommends just placing it inside the bottom navbar.

But to answer your question: spent a good two days figuring this out. Turns out you can just wrap your FAB in a `Box` and use `Modifier.offset`. As far as I can tell, `pointerInput` is accurate as well. There are probably a few ways to do this, and this is likely far from the best.

You'll probably need to manually compute the exact offset you're looking for based on screen size, height of the bottom nav, etcetera. But this is a relatively easy way to achieve the docked FAB, at least.

```
Scaffold(
    modifier = Modifier,
    floatingActionButton = {
        Box(){
            FloatingActionButton(
                onClick = { /* stub */ },
                shape = CircleShape,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .align(Alignment.Center)
                    .size(80.dp)
                    .offset(y = 50.dp)
            ) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = FontAwesomeIcons.Solid.Plus,
                    contentDescription = null,
                    modifier = Modifier.size(45.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    },
    floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.Center,
    content = { Content() },
    bottomBar = {
        BottomNavWr(
            navController,
            tabs
        )
    }
)
```

Produces something similar to the following, depending on other code:

[image]

Comment: Super helpful, thx. Looks like the FAB is by default positioned 16dp above the bar, so to get it to overlay halfway I'm using
`val navigationBarHeight = 80.dp
  val fabOffset = 16.dp // margin above nav bar
  val offset = (navigationBarHeight / 2) + fabOffset`

Answer (score 2):

Material 3 recommends putting Floating Action Bar inside the Bottom Bar, without the cutoff.

If you need the cutoff, use Material 2 components or create a custom one.

If you prefer to follow Material 3 guidelines, put the FAB inside the bar like the following:

```
Scaffold(
    bottomBar = {
        BottomAppBar(
            actions = {},
            floatingActionButton = {
                FloatingActionButton(onClick = { }) {
                    Icon(Icons.Default.Add, contentDescription = "Add")
                }
            },
        )
    }
) {
    Text("The content", modifier = Modifier.padding(it))
}
```

Answer (score -2):

One of the options is to use scaffold and you can set up "floatingActionButtonPosition"

```
 Scaffold(
    bottomBar = { //bottomBar sample },
    floatingActionButton = {
        //Button
    },
    floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.Center,
    content = {//your content
```

Comment: This is not really what he is asking for, the position centered is just one step, we still need the equivalent of what `isFloatingActionButtonDocked` and `cutoutShape` were doing in compose material 2 but now for material 3

Answer (score -3):

I am not using the Material Compose library, but recently I was having the same problem while migrating from Material 2 to Material 3.

https://pasteboard.co/LWzXHPOg3waX.jpg

Adding the **app:fabAnchorMode="cradle"** attribute on my BottomAppBar compenent fixed the issue for me.

https://pasteboard.co/qmZE2NQovGFq.png

Here a code sample

```
 <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/my_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/my_fab_description"
        android:src="?attr/myFabIcon"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/my_bottom_app_bar" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/my_bottom_app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/global_action_bar_height"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:backgroundTint="?attr/myBottomAppBarColor"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="end"
        app:fabAnchorMode="cradle"
        app:fabCradleMargin="@dimen/bottom_action_bar_fab_cradle_margin"
        app:hideOnScroll="true"
        app:menu="@menu/my_bottom_app_bar_menu" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```