# How to create a docked/cradled fab in Material 3 Bottom App Bar similar to Google Keep

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, material-components-android, android-bottomappbar

Recently, I have been trying to create a docked/cradled fab in a bottom app bar in Material 3. While material 2 supports this as default, material 3 has placed the fab within the bottom app bar completely.

[Material 2 Bottom App Bar with cradled fab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cnj5.png)
[Material 3 Bottom App Bar with fab in the corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5ZZy.png)

At first I thought it was simply not in the spec anymore. However, the bottom app bar of Google Keep appears to have a cradled Material 3 fab:

[Material 3 Bottom App Bar with cradled fab from Google Keep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UIcV.png)

As such, I would like to ask how to create this style of bottom app bar (with a cradled fab) in Material 3 with xml.

While looking for similar questions on StackOverflow, I stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73841364/how-to-make-cradled-fab-in-jetpack-compose-material-3),
which while similar to mine, asks how to recreate the effect specifically in compose, and lacks an answer. Strangely, it uses an image of a cradled Material 3 fab which appears to have been removed from the Material 3 documentation linked in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I was assigned the same task by my designer team. After conducting research, I found a solution. While it didn't completely address my issue, it resolved 95% of my problems.

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.graphics.Path
import android.graphics.Point
import android.util.AttributeSet
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView


class CurvedBottomNavigationView : BottomNavigationView {
    private var mPath: Path? = null
    private var mPaint: Paint? = null

    /** the CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS represent the radius of the fab button  */
    private val CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS = 180 / 2

    // the coordinates of the first curve
    private val mFirstCurveStartPoint = Point()
    private val mFirstCurveEndPoint = Point()
    private val mFirstCurveControlPoint1 = Point()
    private val mFirstCurveControlPoint2 = Point()

    //the coordinates of the second curve
    private var mSecondCurveStartPoint = Point()
    private val mSecondCurveEndPoint = Point()
    private val mSecondCurveControlPoint1 = Point()
    private val mSecondCurveControlPoint2 = Point()
    private var mNavigationBarWidth = 0
    private var mNavigationBarHeight = 0

    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context!!) {
        init()
    }

    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(
        context!!, attrs
    ) {
        init()
    }

    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
        context!!, attrs, defStyleAttr
    ) {
        init()
    }

    private fun init() {
        mPath = Path()
        mPaint = Paint()
        mPaint!!.style = Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE
        mPaint!!.color = Color.WHITE
        setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
    }

    override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom)
    }

    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
        // get width and height of navigation bar
        // Navigation bar bounds (width & height)
        mNavigationBarWidth = width
        mNavigationBarHeight = height
        // the coordinates (x,y) of the start point before curve
        mFirstCurveStartPoint[mNavigationBarWidth / 2 - CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2 - CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 3] =
            0
        // the coordinates (x,y) of the end point after curve
        mFirstCurveEndPoint[mNavigationBarWidth / 2] = CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 4
        // same thing for the second curve
        mSecondCurveStartPoint = mFirstCurveEndPoint
        mSecondCurveEndPoint[mNavigationBarWidth / 2 + CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2 + CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 3] =
            0

        // the coordinates (x,y)  of the 1st control point on a cubic curve
        mFirstCurveControlPoint1[mFirstCurveStartPoint.x + CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 4] =
            mFirstCurveStartPoint.y
        // the coordinates (x,y)  of the 2nd control point on a cubic curve
        mFirstCurveControlPoint2[mFirstCurveEndPoint.x - CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2 + CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS] =
            mFirstCurveEndPoint.y
        mSecondCurveControlPoint1[mSecondCurveStartPoint.x + CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2 - CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS] =
            mSecondCurveStartPoint.y
        mSecondCurveControlPoint2[mSecondCurveEndPoint.x - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 4)] =
            mSecondCurveEndPoint.y
        mPath!!.reset()
        mPath!!.moveTo(0f, 0f)
        mPath!!.lineTo(mFirstCurveStartPoint.x.toFloat(), mFirstCurveStartPoint.y.toFloat())
        mPath!!.cubicTo(
            mFirstCurveControlPoint1.x.toFloat(), mFirstCurveControlPoint1.y.toFloat(),
            mFirstCurveControlPoint2.x.toFloat(), mFirstCurveControlPoint2.y.toFloat(),
            mFirstCurveEndPoint.x.toFloat(), mFirstCurveEndPoint.y.toFloat()
        )
        mPath!!.cubicTo(
            mSecondCurveControlPoint1.x.toFloat(), mSecondCurveControlPoint1.y.toFloat(),
            mSecondCurveControlPoint2.x.toFloat(), mSecondCurveControlPoint2.y.toFloat(),
            mSecondCurveEndPoint.x.toFloat(), mSecondCurveEndPoint.y.toFloat()
        )
        mPath!!.lineTo(mNavigationBarWidth.toFloat(), 0f)
        mPath!!.lineTo(mNavigationBarWidth.toFloat(), mNavigationBarHeight.toFloat())
        mPath!!.lineTo(0f, mNavigationBarHeight.toFloat())
        mPath!!.close()
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        canvas.drawPath(mPath!!, mPaint!!)
    }
}
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
   
    <com.Views.Utils.CustomBottomNav.CurvedBottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/ime_md_theme_onPrimaryContainer"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />

    <com.Views.Utils.CustomFloatingButton.CustomFloatingButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/ime_md_theme_primary"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:elevation="8dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="fill_vertical|center_horizontal"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_qr_code" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```